# Какой код верхнего тире, есть ли он вообще?

Tags: символы

Надчеркивание, только по всей ширине глифа. Нашел 00AF, но он короткий

Comment: <http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm> "DENTISTRY SYMBOL LIGHT ..." - был вопрос про углы в комментариях, но нет уже...

Comment: Еще раз извиняюсь, я ошибся, и мне углы не нужны. Только _ (вверху в полный размер). По ссылке не нашел такого

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/203e/index.htm

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0305/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верхний минус (например, для отрицательной степени): 'SUPERSCRIPT MINUS' 0x207B⁻

А это больше похоже на "надчёркивание": 'COMBINING OVERLINE' 0x305̅

Comment: Извините, а можно поподробнее?

Comment: 203E - более менее. Спасибо

Comment: @Herrgott: посмотрите ещё на [consfusables такие как U+ffe3 ￣](https://codepoints.net/U+203E)